# How to enable or disable menu items based on SelectedItems in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, contextmenu

Is there a way to do this when the `ContextMenu` itself is defined inside the `ListBox`?

I have my ListBox set up like this:

```
<ListBox Name="lbxFoundFiles" Margin="10,115,10,5" SelectionMode="Multiple"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            ItemsSource="{Binding FoundFilesInfo}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource FoundFilesListItem}">
    <ListBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Name="cmiCopyClipboard" Header="Copy file to clipboard" Click="cmiCopyClipboard_Click"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=lbxFoundFiles, Path=SelectedItems.Count}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListBox.ContextMenu>
</ListBox>
```

But the error message is clear about this (altough IntelliSense does know what I'm looking for):

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=lbxFoundFiles'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItems; DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name='cmiCopyClipboard'); target property is 'IsEnabled' (type 'Boolean')
```

I've seen examples on how to do this when the ContextMenu is defined outside the ListBox, but I need it to work so I can define a static template for all my listboxes.

**UPDATE**

I have prepared a converter for this, but I've read that my original method should work too.

```
<MenuItem Name="cmiCopyClipboard" Header="Copy file to clipboard" Click="cmiCopyClipboard_Click"
                            IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=lbxFoundFiles, Path=SelectedItems, Converter={StaticResource HasItems}}"/>
```

And converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return ((IList<FileInformation>)value).Count > 0;
}
```

Comment: You are binding IsEnabled property(which is boolean) to SelectedItems.Count(integer). You need converter for that

Comment: Normally Contextual menu are out of the visual tree, that's why you get the error.

Comment: MajkeloDev: I've updated my question to reflect on your suggestion

Comment: @Guerudo: Then how do you suggest I do that? With parent of ancestor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `ListBox` you need to refer to `PlacementTarget` of `ContextMenu` and you can do that via `RelativeSource` binding

```xml
<MenuItem ... 
    IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems, Converter={StaticResource HasItems}}"/>
```

Comment: Perfect! I'll look into this further to get a better understanding. Thanks!

Comment: It's basically to do with how `Popup` works. Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749018(v=vs.110).aspx) link but in short _Popup control does not have its own visual tree...when you set the IsOpen property of Popup to true, a new window with its own visual tree is created_

Comment: That's nice, thanks. I was under the impression that this new visual tree would be inheriting the page it was created on and that it would therefore inherit at least the context of it's "structural" parent or page.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I had to do this I refered to the following article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80632/WPF-Context-Menu-on-List-Item